# I'm trying to find the highest mark and lowest mark in an array with prompts

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my teacher assigned us an assignment to make a program to find the highest and lowest mark of a maximum of 15 students. So it's possible to put in less than 15 students. The user must input the student's name and after the student's mark. After all the student's names and marks have entered, it's suppose to compare the marks to find the least and the greatest.

CODE:

```
var Students = ["sn1", "sn2", "sn3", "sn4", "sn5", "sn6", "sn7", "sn8", "sn9", "sn10", "sn11", "sn12", "sn13", "sn14", "sn15"]; //student's name array
var Marks = ["sm1", "sm2", "sm3", "sm4", "sm5", "sm6", "sm7", "sm8", "sm9", "sm10", "sm11", "sm12", "sm13", "sm14", "sm15"]; //student's marks array
Students[0] = prompt("Student 1's name.");
    if(Students[0].length == 0) { 
        Marks[0] = null
    } else {
        Marks[0] = prompt("Student 1's mark."); //I just copied and pasted this 15 times and changed  the [0] to the next number.
        while(isNaN(Marks[0]) || Marks[0] >= 101 || Marks[0] <= -101) { //if number is greater than or equal to 101, or less than or equal to -1. Prevents a mark higher than 100 and less than 0.
        window.alert("Please input a number between 0-100.");
        Marks[0] = 0
        Marks[0] = prompt("Student 1's mark."); //reprompt.
    }
}
console.log(Students[0] + " " + Marks[0]); //displays mark.

var greatest = -100; //my friend did this part so I don't know if it's right.
var least = 100;
var trackg = 0;
var trackl = 0;
if (Marks[x] != null){ //if this isn't here then I get an error with null.length can't be measured below.
    for(var x = 0; x < Marks.length; x ++) {
        if(Marks[x].length == 2) {
            " " + Marks[x];
        }
        if(Marks[x] >= greatest && Marks[x] != null) {
            greatest = Marks[x]
            trackg = x
        }
    }
}
for(var j = 0; j < Marks.length; j ++) { //the marks[x] != null doesn't work here. it will show that the greatest number is the least number as well which it isn't.
    if (Marks[j] <= least && Marks[j] != null){
            least = Marks[j];
            trackl = j;
    }
}
console.log(Students[trackg] + " has the highest mark of " + Marks[trackg] + ". " + Students[trackl] + " has the lowest mark of " + Marks[trackl] + ".");
```

PROBLEMS:
1. When it compares the number it just takes the first number as the largest number and that's it. So lets say I put the first student's mark as 99 and after I put the 2nd student's as 100. It says 99 is the highest mark and same with negatives for the lowest.

2.I also get that if I put in 100, numbers like 29, 99, etc are higher numbers due to 1 < 2 or 9 etc.

3.For negative numbers, If I put -13 and -99, -13 says it's the lowest which it isn't.

4. Also, if I put in 10 and 100 (even as negatives), 10 is greater/ the least.

I've tried so many things and I don't know whats wrong. (Btw this is my first time with javascript). This assignments due Monday. Thanks ;A;

Comment: Wherever you're comparing use parseInt(number) for all the marks and stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you could do it. Note how the validation is done, and conversion of user input to an actual number for comparison. Only one main loop is necessary; the while loops are to ensure the user enters valid data.

You do not need to actually store all the students' data as an array to display the highest and lowest result.

```js
var students = [];
var numOfStudents, highest = { mark:-1 }, lowest = { mark:101 };

// Get number of students between 1 and 15
while (isNaN(numOfStudents) || numOfStudents <= 0 || numOfStudents > 15)
    numOfStudents = parseInt(prompt('How many students? (1-15)', '1'), 10);

// For each student, get the name and mark
for (i = 1; i <= numOfStudents; i++) {

    var student = {};
    while (typeof student.name === 'undefined' || student.name == '')
        student.name = prompt('Enter Student '+i+' name:', '');
    
    while (typeof student.mark === 'undefined' || isNaN(student.mark) || student.mark < 0 || student.mark > 100)
        student.mark = parseFloat(prompt('Enter Student '+i+' mark (0-100):', ''));
    
    // Check if highest or lowest
    if(student.mark > highest.mark) highest = student;
    if(student.mark < lowest.mark) lowest = student;
    
    // Save current student to the list (optional)
    students.push(student);
}

// Display result
document.body.innerHTML = highest.name + " has the highest mark of " + highest.mark + ". " + lowest.name + " has the lowest mark of " + lowest.mark + ".";
```

Comment: This works a lot better. Thanks. I just changed a few things up to work with the assignment. Youre a great help!